# How to get Loan Status from Deduction table using sql Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Loan Table

[Above image loan table information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgzm4.png)

Deduction table

[Deduction Table Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IS2U.png)

Above Using 2 tables I need to get a loan status for all particular loan in loan table
Below Stored Procedure  I used to getting a loan information where I need to alter to set the status for  all particular loans

Stored Procedure for Getting a loan Status

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetLoan]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @CompanyID  INT,
    @LoanID     BIGINT,
    @EmployeeID BIGINT

AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;
    


    SELECT  e.EmployeeNumber, (e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName) AS EmployeeName,s.SubCompanyName,l.* 
    FROM [dbo].[Loans] l    
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employees] e ON l.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    inner join SubCompanies s on s.SubCompanyID=l.CompanyID
    WHERE ISNULL(l.IsActive, 1) = 1 
    --AND l.CompanyID = @CompanyID
    AND (l.LoanID = @LoanID OR ISNULL(@LoanID, 0) = 0)
    AND (l.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID OR ISNULL(@EmployeeID, 0) = 0)


END
```

Comment: please use left outer join or right outer join

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 ..I used about Joins it getting duplication records

Comment: @DaleK ok.......

Comment: Aside... Please be aware that `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` will break in a future version of SQL Server. As per [SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), _In a future version of SQL Server CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature._

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.